# Project Euler #22 Names Scores - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling to find the logical error in my code. So I'm kindly asking you to help me find the problem.

> Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

Thank all of you for pointing out to the part overlooked by me. Already edited. The answer it gives me is **871179673**, whereas the correct answer is **871198282**

```
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
alpha_d = {}
letter_score, total_score = 0, 0


for ind, let in enumerate(alphabet, start=1):  # Assigning all letters and their indexes to the dictionary
    alpha_d[let] = ind


with open("name.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = str(lines).split(",")  # Opening the file and assigning the string to "lines"
    lines = sorted(lines)


for index, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):  # This 'for' goes through all the names
    line = line.upper()
    letter_score = 0

    for letter in list(line):  # This 'for' goes through the letter in the name
        if letter in alpha_d:
            letter_score += alpha_d[letter]  # If the letter is in the dictionary, it's score will be added

    total_score += (letter_score * index)  # The final score will be added to 'total score'
```

Comment: Why are you repeatedly using `start=1` with enumerate? Also be aware of the string module which allows you to do things like `string.ascii_uppercase.index('F')`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). I know this might not be homework per se, but the same advice applies: "Ask about *specific* problems with your existing implementation". We're not going to debug your entire program for you. When you tried your own debugging, did you find *any* problems? For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

Comment: For completion the input file is here https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt

Comment: Also, for debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including example input *in the question itself*, meaning that that input file will be way too big. Try recreating the issue with a smaller file.

Comment: wjandera, I'm sorry. I saw others do the same and I thought I could give it a try. Next time I'll be more precise!

Comment: A trick to get your list of names sorted: `lines = sorted(eval(open('names.txt').read()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# read your file and sort it
lines = sorted(eval(open('names.txt').read()))

total_score = 0
for index, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
    total_score += index * sum(ord(c) - 64 for c in line)

# Alternative with alphabet
total_score = 0
for index, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
    total_score += index * sum(alphabet.index(c)+1 for c in line)
```

Output:

```
>>> total_score
871198282
```

**Without sort file, the `total_score` is 850081394.**

Source: https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt

Comment: It could save the  square bracket: `[ ....]` in the `sum([ord..... ])` Question - why to use  the `eval` here - can you elaborate it?

Comment: I used `eval` to convert the content of the file into a list because the content is well formatted to be evaluate as a list of strings. It's just a shortcut to have the list.

Answer (score 1):

"Begin by sorting it into alphabetical order" It doesn't seem you have!

Comment: You are right. I overlooked that part. But still it gives the wrong answer **871179673**, but the correct answer is **871198282**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the difference comes from the order of the names. I don't see where you sorted the list before iterating through the names.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was so obvious. Thank you! It still gives me a wrong answer **871179673**, which is off by 18609, but now I'll try to find the problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

Well it only works for sorted arrays as the index of the word will be different in an unsorted array, which will make the `total_score` wrong.

Also, in the line `lines = str(lines).split(",")` of your code, the `str(lines)` considers the brackets of list too i.e `[]`, which you managed by adding an `if` to check if the letter from the string is in the dictionary of alphabets. Now without that `if` it would work much faster. So you modify the string to its needs by stripping it off of `"`, `[`, `,`, `]`.

One more suggestion that which I would like to suggest is that, you can use `f.read()` to read the entire file as a string which will be even more helpful as you can remove the unwanted things and get the names alone... Like this

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase as upper

total_score = 0

with open("names.txt") as f:
    data = f.read().split(",") # Removes the comma, so as to get names along with quotes

L1 = sorted([_.strip('"') for _ in data]) # Removes the individual quotes and sorts the list as well

for i in L1:
    letter_score = sum([upper.index(j)+1 for j in i]) # Sums up the index of individual letters in the words so as to get letter score

    total_score += letter_score*(L1.index(i)+1)

print(total_score)
```